# Node materials not seen in Microsoft Flight Simulator

Tags: export

I have applied a 'node material' to some surfaces of my model which displays correctly in Blender. However when I export as 'extended glTF 2.0 (glb/gltf) for MSFS' (a plugin for Blender) and incorporate the output files into MSFS, my models display with all surfaces which have a texture image applied but the surfaces using the 'node material' display as white in color. Obviously the node texture is not being exported. There are a number of 'parameters' for this export type and I have set all the ones I know of but maybe there is something else I need to do.
Does anyone know? Do I need to 'bake', or 'cycle' (both of which I know nothing about)

Comment: Most other render engines (including those found in game engines) don't understand blender's shader node system. The preferred method for textures generated within blender is to _bake_ these textures into bitmap (image) format, which can then be applied as an image texture in other engines Look into _texture baking_ for these materials.

Comment: Thanks. Another thing learned.

Comment: I have looked at a few youtube videos on texture baking which seemed more complex than what I am prepared to attempt to follow (some if not all  also appeared to include creating the nodes which seemed to go on an on and I lost interest). Is it complex? Are there simple tutorials I can look at? I want to keep learning things but maybe this is one for a 'rainy day afternoon'?

Comment: Try this one  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLQFopN--LY

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I had found that tutorial earlier on however like a lot of other tutorials they are in LOW resolution and I cannot read and of the text displayed in the nodes which makes it very difficult if not impossible to follow. I downloaded the video tutorial as a 1080p video which improved the lack of sharpness a little but it is still difficult to read. I will try again. Sorry some more. As baking created a texture image wouldn't I then be 'back at square one'? Wouldn't that then be uv wrapped onto my object and create a 'pattern' on large surfaces?

Comment: Watching the downloaded video and replaying parts of it a few times and switching between the video and my Blender work space (as I still could not read some of the text) I think I now understand it (looks simple enough) I will try it tomorrow. Still not convinced though that I won't end up with a 'tiled pattern' look. I will do that tomorrow.

Comment: I have done it. Mind you baking seems to take forever (4K) - only at 11% after 2 or 3 minutes and I have an i7 CPU.   Thanks again.